# What do the parts of malevolent and malicious mean?

Tags: meaning, learning

I understand what the different parts of maladjusted, maligned, and malcontent mean.

But what about malevolent and malicious?

Could someone break these into parts e.g. mal - adjust - ed and explain the meaning of each of the parts for both of these words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php) is your best friend in this kind of situations:

> [**malevolent**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=malevolent&searchmode=none) c.1500, from O.Fr. *malivolent*, from L. *malevolentem* (nom. *malevolens*) "ill-disposed, envious," from *male* "badly" + *volentem* (nom. *volens*), prp. of *velle* "to wish".
>
> [**malicious**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=malicious&searchmode=none) early 13c., from O.Fr. *malicius* "showing ill will," from L. *malitiosus* "wicked, malicious," from *malitia* "badness, ill will, spite," from *malus* "bad".

**Edit:** "O.Fr." stands for Old French (the French language as written and spoken around 900–1400), and "L." for Classical Latin (the language of ancient Rome until about 4th century).

Answer (score 4):

**Malevolent**

from Latin *malevolens*, from *male* ill + *volens*, present participle of *velle* to wish

**Malicious**

Middle English, from Anglo-French, from Latin *malitia*, from *malus* bad

Both words mean bad, and are pretty much synonymous, but *malevolent* may have more of a feeling of potential evil smoldering within a person, while malicious could used to describe actual evil that has been demonstrated. Example:

> I knew he was a malevolent S.O.B., 
>   but I never dreamed he would
>   perform such a malicious act.

Comment: +1 *malevolent* = wishing ill harm, a *malevolent* person is one that wishes, or desires ill harm (to others).

Answer (score 2):

Maladjusted

mal(us) - Latin for "bad".
ad - Latin for "to"
justus - fair or correct (we get "justice" from "justitia", which is related)

Malign

See above, and 
gignere - to bring about, to give birth to

Malcontent

contentus - contained, hence, self-contained.

Malevolent

volens - wishing

Malicious

In Latin the suffix "itia" means, having the quality of, or full of (hence, "justitia' - see above". So you start with "malitia", and this elides over time to "malicious".